# exterior of a set $A=\{1-\frac{(-1)^n}{n}:n\in \mathbb{N}\}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

given the set $A=\{1-\frac{(-1)^n}{n}:n\in \mathbb{N}\}$, find $\operatorname{int}(A)$, $\partial A$, $\overline{A}$ and $\operatorname{ext}(A)$.

where each represents the interior of $A,$ border of $A,$ closure of $A,$ exterior of $A$ respectively.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but without so much detail I got the following:

$\operatorname{int}(A)=\emptyset$ ; $\overline{A}=\{1-\frac{(-1)^n}{n}:n\in \mathbb{N}\}\cup\{1\}=\partial A$ and I'm having trouble determining who is $\operatorname{ext}(A) $. Any suggestions are welcome, thanks in advance.

Comment: The exterior can be shown to be the complement of the closure. Since you have found $\overline{A}$, you only need to take its complement.

Comment: $\mathbb{R}=\operatorname{int}(A)\cup\partial A\cup\operatorname{ext}(A)=\overline{A}\cup\operatorname{ext}(A)$ and if $\overline{A}$ and $\operatorname{ext}(A)$ are disjoint then I can deduce that $\mathbb{R}-\overline{A}=\operatorname{ext}(A)$?

Comment: Yes. In fact, the unions above are all disjoint unions.

Comment: Wow! just great, thanks for your help.